# closing unity game after a score is reached

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity which is started by a button click on Windows Form Application and I want to close the game and return to the form when the score equals to 18. My current code does not quit the game upon reaching that score.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public Text scoretext;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoretext.text = Player.position.z.ToString("0");
        if (scoretext.text == "18")
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Quit()` indeed is the correct method for this.

Have you confirmed through breakpoint or log that this line of code is being reached?

I'd also recommend rearranging things to not be relying on the comparison of the string for something like this.

```
int score = (int)player.position.z;

scoreText.text = score.ToString();

if (score >= 18)
{
    Application.Quit()
}
```

Comment: Note: Application.Quit() doesnt work in editor. Make a build and test there

Comment: Yes I did not know this previously that this method works only after building the game. Thanks for the help